# 'Undefined' passed from parent to child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have the following code with a parent and a child class, The parent class is the Container and the child presents the results on the screen.However I am unable to pass values from parent to child. Whenever I try to pass the value, I get undefined

Parent Class

```js
class Container extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {course:"Commerce",grade:"10",btnState:"Add"}
}
render(){

        return (
          <Presentation course={this.state.course} grade={this.state.grade} btnState={this.state.btnState}
           />
        );
    }
}
```

Child Class

```js
class Presentation extends React.Component {
     debug(){
       alert(this.props.course)
     }
    render () {
  return (
    <div>

        <form>

            <input type="text" value={this.props.course} /><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" value={this.props.grade}  /><br/><br/>
            <input type="reset" id="addCourse" value={this.props.btnState} 
  onClick={this.debug.bind(this)}/>
            </form>
    </div>
  );
}
   }
```

The Rendering

```js
ReactDOM.render(
      <Presentation />
      , 
      document.querySelector("#container1")
    );
```

The form is rendering correctly but the values are not being passed into the child from the parent. `alert(this.props.course}` gives undefined

Comment: Is this your exact code? are you not making an api call somewhere to get data maybe?

Comment: Can you just `console.log(this.props);` in render of `<Presentation>`

Comment: It does not print anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you have a container component, but you're directly rendering the child component `Presentation`.

> ```
> ReactDOM.render(
>       <Presentation />
>       , 
>       document.querySelector("#container1")
>     );
> ```

Try rendering the container, e.g.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Container />,
  document.querySelector("#container1")
);
```

And see if that renders the container, creates state, and passes the expected props to `Presentation`.